# My theme changes are not visible on frontend

Tags: magento2

I have a custom theme
dir `app/design/frontend/Test/Theme`

but my changes are not reflecting on frontend  and am using a custom css file

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create `default_head_blocks.xml` like below locations in your theme

```
app/design/frontend/Test/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

and add the below code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/yourcustomstyle.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Step 2: create your `css` file at below locations

```
app/design/frontend/Test/Theme/web/css/yourcustomstyle.css
```

Step 3:-
now go to `pub/static/frontend` and delete everything inside `frontend` folder.
now run below commands

```
<root>php bin/magento setup:upgrade
<root>php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f
<root>php bin/magento cache:Clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please what process or steps did you use? please try to run these once you made changes to your themes:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:Deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:Clean
```

Run these commands in root